# How are the two Stacking Faults namely intrinsic(formed by vacancy agglomeration) and extrinsic(formed by interstitial agglomeration) different?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, metals

[image]

Stacking Faults and its association with partial dislocations seem to bother me day in and day out.With regard to this I do not understand how Partial dislocations lead to stacking faults and not the Perfect ones.Similarly in this context Please explain me how the Vacancy agglomeration and interstitial agglomeration will be different in mechanism and will lead to different results.

Comment: Well, one is an ‘innie’ and one is an ‘outie’ to put it in layman’s terms. Consider, not the side view of one edge as you show, but what the initial nucleation looks like.

Comment: @JonCuster Thankyou but could you elaborate more on this?